# Best practice for copying argument passed by reference to method that avoids unintentionally modifying argument

Tags: python, copy, pass-by-reference

My intention when executing the following line of code was to use cv2 to draw on my original image (i.e., img). As best I can tell, it did so but modified img (which was not desired).

```
cbImg = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (nx, ny), corners, ret)
```

I understand that Python is pass-by-reference, which means the argument can be changed by the method. To avoid modifying the original image, it is necessary to operate on a copy (e.g., as shown below)

```
cbImg = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(copy.copy(img), (nx, ny), corners, ret)
```

I passed a copy to cv2.drawChessboardCorners() because I cannot modify the method. However, I have seen a number of examples where the copy is performed within the method.

Is there a best practice regarding where copying should take place? In other words, if I am using someone else's method, should I always pass a copy to ensure my original image is not modified? Alternatively, when writing my own methods, should I always (or never) perform a copy within my method to ensure that I do not unintentionally modify someone else's argument? Furthermore, is it generally advisable to assume an argument passed by reference should be modified (or not)?

Comment: objects **are never passed by reference** in Python. Python does not support pass-by-reference semantics, and all function calls use the same evaluation strategy.

Comment: In other words, "I understand that Python is pass-by-reference, which means the argument can be changed by the method." is wrong. In pass-by-reference, assignment to the argument will be seen *in the caller*, i.e. `f(x): x = 13` will cause `f(y)` in the caller to reassign `y`. You'll find this is not the case in Python. The technical name is ["call by sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) sometimes called "pass by assignment" in Python. Note, this is the same strategy that most modern languages use, so Java, Ruby, Javascript etc.

Comment: Edited question to "argument" rather than "object". If there is better terminology to ask the question, I am happy to edit question further for the sake of clarification. The underlying question remains the same...the method modifies what is passed to it. Is there a best practice as to where copying is performed (i.e., pass copy to method, or make copy within method)?

Comment: The terminology nitpick was *not* about the use of argument vs object, (indeed, in this case object is more clear). Rather, it is about the term "pass by reference" which is simply incorrect in the case of Python (i.e., it is not supported in Python). I agree, though, that the underlying question is a good one and not really affected, but this misuse of terminology is one of my pet peeves.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd really like to know who started that "Python isn't pass by reference" nonsense. I suspect some C++ guy who doesn't know that Python's references are simply something else than C++'s references.

Comment: @stefanpochmann I don't think it is nonesense. Python doesnt really have a reference type to begin with, rather, variables act like pointers to Python objects that get derefenced for you when you access them. But regardless, just because you pass a reference doesn't mean the language supports pass by reference semantics. For example, you can pass a pointer in C and simulate pass by reference, but you still don't have pass-by-reference semantics in C.

Comment: @StefanPochmann When people say Python isn't pass-by-reference, they mean that you can't make this happen in Python:  `x = 1; set_to_two(x); assert x == 2;`  In C++, pass-by-reference means a reference to a name. Python has no references to names.  But it does pass all values as references to values, leading to the terminology conflict.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python has references. Just not the kind that C++ has. And when you're passing references and say it's not call-by-reference, I think your definition of call-by-reference doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yeah, I know. That's why I said I suspect some C++ guy made that up. And I'd be ok with people saying Python isn't call-by-reference-where-with-reference-I-mean-like-C++-reference.

Comment: My preference is to avoid shorthand phrases and explain things in full where needed:  https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html   It's hard to reuse words across languages.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yeah, I agree. Particularly with the "where needed". In this case, I don't think it was needed at all. Or in any way helpful. I don't think the OP is confusing Python's references with C++'s references. (I've btw read your stuff about this before and recognized your name right away, pleasure to "meet" you :-)

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on terminology, I am coming from a novice Java background and the way Python deals with arguments appears to be different than what I was expecting. I came across a webpage that indicates "Python initially behaves like call-by-reference, but as soon as we are changing the value of such a variable, Python "switches" to call-by-value" (https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php). The discussion under "Side effects" provides an example to further illustrate the difference.

Comment: I'm not a fan of "switches" to explain this, since all values and all assignments are treated exactly the same, always.

Comment: @user2514157 yeah, I think that the link is simply trying to explain it using those concepts. But it states correctly: "To come back to our initial question what is used in Python: The authors who call the mechanism call-by-value and those who call it call-by-reference are stretching the definitions until they fit. 
Correctly speaking, Python uses a mechanism, which is known as "Call-by-Object", sometimes also called "Call by Object Reference" or "Call by Sharing"." Note: python's evaluation strategy is the same as Java (except python lack's primitive types).

Comment: @StefanPochmann well, I suppose we can agree to disagree. Passing a reference isn't call-by-reference. Indeed, references are values too, does that make it simultaneously call-by-reference and call-by-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is for functions to be clear about whether they modify their arguments or not.  Ideally, they would not, since that is easier to reason about.  Creating and returning a new value is an option if the data is not large.

Only make copies if you know for a fact that the function modifies its argument, and you definitely need both the original and the modified value.